# unable to send data to my custom password reset blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have just replaced my `reset password` default  template with my `custom template` for `reset password`.

Here is what i have done (I'm using **Laravel 5.4**) :

1. In `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php` changed function now it looks like this :

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
    return (new MailMessage)->with('token', $this->token); 
    // ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
    // ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
    // ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

2. I'm successfully able to send the email
3. But when i try to access the  `{{$token}}`  in `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`, it gives the following `error`

[image]

---

How i'm trying to send data is:

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {    
  return (new MailMessage)->with('token', $this->token);
}
```

in this `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php` `class`  `$token` is public and been assigned inside constructor.

**Question**: How to send `$token` to `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i'm able to send email without `$token` if i do in blade `{{$token}}` i will get error

Comment: Don't modify the files in the vendor directory, just override them in your project code and use the overridden ones.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with following:**

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
  return (new MailMessage)->with('token'=>$this->token); 
}
```